# Actionscript 3: Back History Button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, history, back-button

Sorry in advance. I am new in Actionscript and trying to implement a history back button, not a go to previous frame button; in a flash movie, not in a flash web page). My approach is to use an array and push the currentframe to it on any visited frame. My code is not working and it is giving back an error #1502.

Please help me to fix the code I have by now:

```
var back:Array = new Array(); //global variable


stop();
back.push(MovieClip(this.root).currentFrame); // in every visited frame 


back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backGoTo);
function backGoTo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (currentLabel)
    {

        case "framelabel":
            for (var i:int = 0; i < back.length; i++)
            {
            gotoAndStop(back[i]); // expected to go to the last visited frame.
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the last element of an array, use `back[back.length-1]`, or if you want to remove the last element and get it back at the same time then `back.pop();`. So in your case, that for cycle has no use, it's all wrong.. nonsense to check all the elements of an array in this case.

```
function Softkey3GoTo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (currentLabel)
    {
        case "m_1":
        case "m_2":
        case "reply":
        case "messages":
            gotoAndStop(back[back.length-2]); // -2 because the current one is -1, the previous frame is -2.
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zhafur: thanks a lot. it is working but is not going trough the history nav is getting in a loop of 2 frames. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Error #1502 is when the script is looping for more than the given interval which is 15 seconds as default. Are you sure you are running the code when it's needed?

Comment: Were to use the back.pop() , in the gotoAndStop ?

Comment: Yes, the pop function removes the last element and returns it.

Comment: Now I need to click twice to get back. Do I need to specify any value to go back by doing only one click? Thanks in advance:

Comment: `function Softkey3GoTo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (currentLabel)
    {
        case "m_1":
        case "m_2":
        case "reply":
        case "messages":
            gotoAndStop(back.pop());
            break;
    }
}`

Comment: Well if you need to click twice, then call the back.pop(); before you call the gotoAndStop(back.pop()); that's it. :)

Comment: thanks a lot Zhafur for your suggestions, actually I could find the solution just before your posted by myself after exploring the .pop method. I suppose that maybe a cleaner way to code this exists but by now is working well. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring the Array .pop method I could find the solution to my back button. here is my code for a global back history button. in every frame you must push it to the array. call the last element of the array and delete it at the same time:

```
var back:Array = new Array(); //global variable


stop();
back.push(MovieClip(this.root).currentFrame); // in every visited frame 


back.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backGoTo);
function backGoTo(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (currentLabel)
    {

        case "framelabel":
            back.pop();
    gotoAndStop(back.pop());
            break;
    }
}
```